# Can we say $i=i_{0}\lvert\sin(\omega t+ \phi) \rvert$ is alternating current?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, terminology, electric-current

$$i=i_{0}\lvert\sin(\omega t+ \phi) \rvert$$

$i_{0}>0$. Can we say that the current described by the above equation is an alternating current?

$$i=i_{0}\sin(\omega t+ \phi)$$ We are mostly familiar with the above equation which describes an alternating current. I think that the the current described by the $1^\mathrm{st}$ equation is a direct current as it doesn't change its direction.The curve describing the $1^\mathrm{st}$ equation is given below:

[image]

As the current doesn't changes its direction but it still has alternating values. Should it be called as alternating current?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think that the the current described by the $1^\mathrm{st}$ equation is a direct current as it doesn't change its direction.

You're welcome to think whatever you want, but when you use language, it is advantageous to stick to the standard accepted terminology, which does **not** use the term "direct current" for anything other than an unchanging voltage that is stable in time. The only thing that you will achieve by calling $i=i_{0}\lvert\sin(\omega t+ \phi) \rvert$ a 'direct current' is to confuse your readers (and, probably, make them extremely cross that you're completely misusing a standard term.

Instead, the current $i=i_{0}\lvert\sin(\omega t+ \phi) \rvert$ is known as a rectified alternating current. Use any other terms at your peril.

Answer (score 0):

Alternating Current is a term given to current which changes in direction and by direction I mean the direction of electron flow. Hence, the terminology cannot be used here. However, the above current function is a pulsating DC Flow, which is periodic.

In simple terms, consider electrons as balls flowing through a pipe. Alternating current describes the motion of balls, whose speeds reduce to zero and then change their direction altogether. However,pulsating DC describes the speed of balls to reduce to zero and increase again but in the same direction.

For more info(and for additional knowledge), refer to the graphs given in this below link:
http://www.visionics.a.se/Full%20Wave%20Rectifier1.aspx

Thanks!Hope it helps!